# Illegal attempt to enlist multiple 1PC XAResources

Tags: spring, mybatis, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions, transactional

We have Multiple Transaction Managers (`WebsphereUOWTransactionManager` and `DatasourceTransactionManager`) and use Mybatis and `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` (legacy code)

The code used to work and the changes made are to move `@Transactional` to the Service Level and remove `sqlsession.commit` from the mybatis code.

But now there is an issue where the legacy code (`JdbcTemplate`) is executed.

**The error is**

```
20170427 19:22:02.045 [SimpleThreadPoolWorker-2] DEBUG o.s.b.c.r.d.JdbcStepExecutionDao # Truncating long message before update of StepExecution, original message is: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [
                UPDATE JOB_RUN
                SET SYS_RUN_STUS_CD = ?,
                UPDT_USER_ID = 'SYSTEM',
                REC_UPDT_TS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                WHERE  JOB_RUN_ID = ?
            ]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; enlist: caught Exception; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: enlist: caught Exception
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:909)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:933)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:313)
    at com.abc.common.dao.jdbc.JobRunJdbcDao.updateJobStatus(JobRunJdbcDao.java:199)
    at com.abc.common.dao.jdbc.JobRunJdbcDao.updateJobStatus(JobRunJdbcDao.java:193)
    at com.abc.bpe.core.InitializingTasklet.execute(InitializingTasklet.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport$1.doInTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager$UOWActionAdapter.run(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:347)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderCurrentUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:954)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:370)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:290)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:298)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.execute(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager$UOWActionAdapter.run(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:347)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderNewUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:775)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:368)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:290)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:127)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:165)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
    at com.abc.bpe.core.support.CompositeJobLauncher.runJob(CompositeJobLauncher.java:207)
    at com.abc.des.bpe.core.support.CompositeJobLauncher$1.run(CompositeJobLauncher.java:119)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: enlist: caught Exception
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.toSQLException(AdapterUtil.java:1000)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.beginTransactionIfNecessary(WSJdbcConnection.java:513)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.prepareStatement(WSJdbcConnection.java:2373)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.prepareStatement(WSJdbcConnection.java:2339)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.createPreparedStatement(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:238)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:638)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: enlist: caught Exception
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.LocalTransactionWrapper.enlist(LocalTransactionWrapper.java:585)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.lazyEnlist(ConnectionManager.java:1726)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.lazyEnlist(WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.java:2084)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.beginTransactionIfNecessary(WSJdbcConnection.java:468)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to enlist multiple 1PC XAResources
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.enlistResource(RegisteredResources.java:441)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.enlistResource(TransactionImpl.java:2252)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.embeddable.impl.EmbeddableTranManagerSet.enlistOnePhase(EmbeddableTranManagerSet.java:202)
    at com.ibm.ws.transaction.services.TransactionManagerService.enlistOnePhase(TransactionManagerService.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.LocalTransactionWrapper.enlist(LocalTransactionWrapper.java:501)
    ... 67 more
```

I added `@Transactional` to the InitializingTasklet.execute(...) method

Any help regarding this issue is greatly appreciated. Also if any other code needed, please let know

Thanks

**EDIT 3:**

serviceBeans.xml

```
    <tx:advice id="txServiceAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
            <tx:attributes>
                <tx:method name="runJob" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="Throwable" isolation="READ_COMMITTED" />
            </tx:attributes>
        </tx:advice>

<!-- commented the below line now and change the transactionManager-->
        <!-- <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </bean> -->

        <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager" />

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

**EDIT 2:**

I removed multiple transaction managers and now only have the WebspereUOWTransactionManager

**EDIT**

**Additional code:**

**BatchServiceImpl (Added @Transactional):**

```
@Override
    @Transactional(value = "transactionManager", rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void launchJob(JobLaunchRequest request) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            logger.info("Launching job: " + request.getJobParameters().toString());
            jobLauncher.runAll(request.getJobParameters());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

**Code that calls the DAO:**

```
public class ParameterBasedCompositeJobLauncher implements CompositeJobLauncher, InitializingBean {
public Collection<JobExecution> runAll(final Collection<JobExecutionParameters> jobParameterSet)
            throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException,
            JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException {
....
jobRunDao.updateJobStatus(batchId, jobRunStatus);
....
}
}
```

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="add*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" rollback-for="Exception" isolation="READ_COMMITTED" />
            <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" rollback-for="Exception" isolation="READ_COMMITTED" />
        </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

**spring-dataSource.xml**

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />      

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate"
          c:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />
```

**spring-launch-context.xml**

```
<bean id="jobLauncher" class="com.abc.core.support.ParameterBasedCompositeJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
        <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor"/>
        <property name="jobLocator" ref="jobRegistry" />
        <property name="jobRunDao" ref="jobRunDao"/>
        <property name="forwardJobClient" ref="integration-forwardJobClient"/>
        <property name="responseFileGenerator" ref="responseFileGenerator"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor">
        <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobRepository"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
          p:transactionManager-ref="transactionManager"
          p:lobHandler-ref="lobHandler"
          p:tablePrefix="${SCHEMA}.BATCH_"
          p:isolationLevelForCreate="ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED"
          class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean"/>
```

Comment: Try to add `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` on the service method that calls that mybatis query.

Comment: Thanks @Jorge Campos.....You mean the one that calls NamedParameterJdbcTemplate right?

Comment: Not sure, because since I don't know how your architecture is setup, it should be the method of the respective service that calls `com.abc.common.dao.jdbc.JobRunJdbcDao.updateJobStatus` since you said that you moved your `@Transaction` to the service. Note that if this method is being run inside a thread you will need to refactor some. In a thread context the transaction manager can not manage that method another transaction will be created. See this thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275471/calling-transactional-methods-from-another-thread-runnable

Comment: @JorgeCampos Still get the same error. I have added some more relevant code that might be useful. Can you please look at it when you have some time. Thank you

Comment: With your configuration nothing rings a bell sorry. One thing that I thought, does that table `JOB_RUN` has a trigger on it? Also analyzing the stack trace it seems like some sort of conflict between the spring transaction manager and ibm transaction manager, both are are trying to prepare the statement, spring executes it but the transaction is managed by the ibm. There is also something strange here: 2 different classes are trying to enlist the process `at com.ibm.tx.jta.embeddable.impl.EmbeddableTranManagerSet.enlistOnePhase(EmbeddableTranManagerSet.java:202)`...

Comment: `at com.ibm.ws.transaction.services.TransactionManagerService.enlistOnePhase(TransactionManagerService.java:382)` That seems odd. I would download the sources and try to debug it so you can see what is happening.

Comment: @JorgeCampos...Thank you. No trigger on the table. But I have another Edit and added some more relevant code

Comment: Your serviceBeans have the transactionManager named as `txManager` and your batchservice class is using transactionManager. What happens if you change the method `launchJob` to use `@Transactional(value = "txManager"` instead of `transactionManager` ?

Comment: No change...still the same error. Thanks @JorgeCampos

Comment: Check with IBM support? This technote might give a hint on what you should be looking out for https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21244805