# Calling @Transactional methods asynchronously in quarkus

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have an application scoped bean as follows

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Worker {

   public void process(Long id) {
       final Runnable runnable = () -> {
           doATransaction(id);           
      };
      executor.execute(runnable);
    }
    
   @Transactional
    public void doATransaction(Long id) {
        User user  = User.findById(id);
    }
}
```

I am getting a javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException.  I also tried adding the doATransaction() to another Bean, which was injected in this Worker, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275471/calling-transactional-methods-from-another-thread-runnable).  Still had the same problem.

Does anyone have an idea of what I could do next?

The Exception I am getting is

```
Exception in thread "pool-13-thread-3" javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ClientProxies.getDelegate(ClientProxies.java:40)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.RequestScopedSessionHolder_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(RequestScopedSessionHolder_ClientProxy.zig:42)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.RequestScopedSessionHolder_ClientProxy.getOrCreateSession(RequestScopedSessionHolder_ClientProxy.zig:160)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.acquireSession(TransactionScopedSession.java:103)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.find(TransactionScopedSession.java:168)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.ForwardingSession.find(ForwardingSession.java:68)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations.findById(AbstractJpaOperations.java:173)
    at com.example.User.findById(User.java)
```

Comment: Can you please add more details about the `ContextNotActiveException` you get? I suspect it's missing the request context, is that right?

Comment: @Ladicek  I am not sure how I can check that.  The exception I get is  Exception in thread "pool-63-thread-2" javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException
 at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ClientProxies.getDelegate(ClientProxies.java:40)

Comment: Ouch, too bad, I thought the context name will be there :-/ Can you add more of the stacktrace? It might show what bean is being looked up when the exception happens, and consequently what context is inactive. I suspect it's a the request context, anyway, because the transactional things in Quarkus are request-scoped IIRC. Obviously the request context is not active on the new thread, unless you use `ManagedExecutor` from MP Context Propagation, but using that comes with constraints and shouldn't be done blindly.

Comment: @Ladicek  have updated the question

Comment: I think that you execute the transactional method in a different thread than your request and that is why your context is not active.

Comment: Think about using quarkus events https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-event-bus

Comment: And about context propagation in quarkus https://quarkus.io/guides/context-propagation

Comment: OK, as I suspected, it's clearly the request  context. So, here's a thing. Add a dependency on `quarkus-smallrye-context-propagation`, inject a `ManagedExecutor` and use that instead of your own `executor`. That should work, but note that you should _not_ have multiple threads accessing the same request-scoped objects. So this is really meant for cases where request processing sometimes has to hop from one thread to another and then perhaps back, but it's still sequential. If that's your case, it will be enough.

Comment: @Ladicek A bit of terminology clarification here.  Is  the request context, related to the scoped of the bean  (RequestScoped/ApplicationScoped) etc

Comment: Yes, scopes and contexts are closely related. You can think of _context_ as a storage of objects of some _scope_.